# Java boolean does not get seen as true

Tags: java, boolean

I have been having a hard time trying to use booleans recently. Basically, I have no idea why this doesn't work.

In one file I have something like this:

```
public static boolean newboolean;

if (something) {
    newboolean = true;
}
else {
    newboolean = false;
}
```

In the other file I have:

```
if(firstclass.newboolean = true) {
    doSomething()
}
else {
    doSomethingDifferent()
}
```

Basically, if the stuff in the first `if (something)` is true, then `newboolean` should get set to true.

However, instead of doing `doSomething()` it does `doSomethingDifferent()`. However, I know for a fact that the boolean is set to true.

This makes me think that there was a problem telling my second file that it was true, hopefully that makes sense. Can someone help?

Comment: You say "I know for a fact that the boolean is set to true".  Would you care to put a wager on that?  =)      Use a debugger and slowly step through your code and MAKE SURE that that boolean really is true.  If statements don't just fail, so most likely you have a bug somewhere causing your boolean to be false.  The debugger is your friend!

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in your titles.  If an answer has helped you, you may mark it solved by accepting that answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(firstclass.newboolean = true)
```

That is not just a comparison, that is an **assignment**. It makes `newboolean` true.

You want

```
if (firstclass.newboolean)
```

or, if you must spell out `true` (discouraged)

```
if (firstclass.newboolean == true)
```

The Java compiler catches this problem for all other types of conditionals, but unfortunately not for booleans. So better shake the habit of typing the `== true` (or `== false`) part.

Comment: Should maybe add how to do a comparison as well? `==` is what you want to use when comparing.

Comment: @Emz You shouldn't be comparing to `true` or `false`.  You should be using `if (myBool)` or `if (!myBool)`.  Suggesting comparison against boolean literals is bad.

Comment: No you should not, was more a comment for future. If comparing to something else.